# Mixing material design with magazine design

Tags: design-patterns, material-design, frontend-development

I'm trying to create a design that will satisfy both marketing and UI needs.
Material design solves a lot of problems from an application perspective, consistent UI elements such as tables, buttons, tables, controls, etc. But it's not really helpful for marketing, I've seen some pages done with material design and they are poor in terms of persuasion marketing (hard to create the WOW factor).

My question: is there a way to combine those two styles?

Basically I would like to combine this:
https://www.oculus.com/en-us/touch/
http://www.semplicelabs.com/features

With this:
https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/data-tables.html#data-tables-interaction

Comment: You'll likely get better answers at: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I don't see there being an issue with combining the two styles, because in essence Material Design is medium/channel agnostic, i.e. it provides a set of guidelines on designing for various interactions and behaviours, regardless of whether it is digital or in print (or some other yet to be discovered communication medium).

Answer (score 1):

I know what you are talking about because we've been facing similar problems adopting our brand to match material design. Our band is minimalistic and only uses 2 colors(just black and white), so google's emphasis on colors for animation and transitions in material design doesn't exactly work across brands like ours.

The Oculus example you provided reminds me of the apple website.

The solution is to find the right balance, avoid following material design to the book and take careful considerations on every design decision.

For us, we introduced a 3rd bright color that ended up being used and sometimes overused.

Comment: Material was not intended as a prescription, it's a tool kit. Use what works, redesign what doesn't. Bright colors, for instance, are a recommendation, not a rule.

Answer (score 0):

It's odd to me that people get hung up on this. Material is a UI framework, not a brand guideline. But apparently it's a common point of confusion because ...

## Google created case studies to address this question

The Google Design team put together a reference doc appropriately called [**"Expressing Brand in Material"**](https://design.google.com/articles/expressing-brand-in-material/).

> Material design lays the foundation for creating a well-designed and functional product, but we encourage you to think bigger and bolder about how your brand fits into the framework.

They recognize that any UI framework should be flexible enough to harmonize with a given brand.

> You don’t have to adopt every element of the material design system in order for it to be beneficial to your identity system.

[image: Sample branded app from Google]

Comment: Thanks but I think all the examples mentioned in the article are mobile apps.

Comment: @DanielVianna you asked about marketing. Hopefully you can stretch your imagination a bit and imagine one of those tablet views as a desktop site.  There is clearly flexibility to express some brand voice within Material.